# Controlling multiple RPis using SSH (no infrastructure network available)

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-zero-w, wifi-direct

My goal is to be able to access multiple Raspberry Pi Zero Ws (3-5) simultaneously through SSH from a laptop running Linux. This has to be done in an area where there is no infrastructure network available (out in a field in the middle of nowhere), and it has to be done wirelessly. I have, so far, been unsuccessful in accessing even one RPi through SSH with my laptop. I have not been able to create a network connection between the two devices. I have tried creating an ad-hoc network on the laptop using the following forum pages and tutorials, to name a few:

- [Setting up an ad-hoc network with Raspbian Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60267/setting-up-an-ad-hoc-network-with-raspbian-jessie)
- [Ad Hoc setup in RPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/ad-hoc-setup-in-rpi-3/49792)
- [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)
- [Wireless Communication Between Raspberry Pi and Your Computer](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/) - this worked, but the laptop connects to a network created on the Pi, and I need the opposite so that multiple Pis can connect to the 'central' laptop

I am a true beginner. Touched Linux and a Raspberry Pi for the first time last Monday (June 5, 2017). I have spent almost all of my time at work trying to figure this out with no success.

What is the simplest way to simultaneously control multiple RPis (with fresh installs of Raspian Jessie) using a laptop with Linux (Ubuntu)? Remember, there is no infrastructure network where I'll be doing this.

Please let me know if there's other information that I can provide to help.

Comment: What you want to do appears to set up an ad-hoc network on a laptop, which is off-topic for this site. Have you considered just using a cheap wireless router?

Comment: Why not use one of the Pi's to provide wireless services for all the devices to connect to including your laptop.  I think you have one unit working like that now.  The others just need to join the central unit. 
Then using ssh you can connect to each of the units by the assigned ip address.  The laptop can also join the wireless network and ssh into any of the units.

Comment: I will try the network set up through the Pi, since I was successful with that. I'll post in a comment if I can accomplish what I'm trying to do. I'll consider getting a cheap router, since that might end up being simpler for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have successfully accomplished what I was trying to do. I can now SSH into the Pi from a Linux machine. I set up the Pi as an access point using [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) and this site: [Using RPi as WiFi Access Point with hostapd](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/)

Comment: @Fabian Questions older than 60 days like this one [can't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/336144), even by moderators; this question can only be closed on this site instead if it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Per OP's comment:</sup>

I have successfully accomplished what I was trying to do. I can now SSH into the Pi from a Linux machine. I set up the Pi as an access point using [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) and this site: [Using RPi as WiFi Access Point with hostapd](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/)